# `read` doesn't work in disable pseudo-terminal allocation mode

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a need to do a one liner bash which reads the output of `ls`, store the output into a variable, before doing something with that variable like this:

`ls <dir_that_has_just_one_file> | read filename && echo $filename`

This works fine when I'm on the host. However when I am using a bastion host as a jump host, it doesn't work:

`ssh -T <bastion_host> ssh <destination_host> "ls <dir_that_has_just_one_file> | read filename && echo $filename"`

There is no output out of this.

Appreciate if there is any workaround on this. Thank you!

Comment: Try with single quotes around the remote command

Comment: Why do you need to do the `read` remotely?

Comment: Since it's in double-quotes, the `$filename` will be "expanded" by the local shell (presumably to nothing, since `filename` isn't set in the local shell) before it's passed to the `ssh` command, let alone gets to the remote shell.